# React Native) How to display website using React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I'm attempting to build a website using React Native Web,
and have been stuck on trying to display my website using Expo.
My expectation is that I will be able to see it when I click "Run in web browser"
(it should open a blank page with an intro text)
but it only returns back to the Expo page.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebView to display web pages on React Native Expo apps.

First, install react-native-webview by this command.

```js
expo install react-native-webview
```

Then you could add this WebView as shown below.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView 
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: 'https://expo.dev' }}
    />
  );
}
```

You can also insert custom web (html) page like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      style={styles.container}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={{ html: '<h1><center>Hello world</center></h1>' }}
    />
  );
}
```

To know more you can read this doc [expo webview](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webview/)

Comment: react-native-webview is not rendered in Expo